# JavaFX TextInputControl requestFocus

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I'm trying to call requestFocus method from a TextInputControl. Without success.
I want to set focus on a TextInputControl when I open a new Tab. I'm doing this:

```
tab.setContent(anchor);
tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);

SingleSelectionModel<Tab> selectionModel = tabPane.getSelectionModel();
selectionModel.select(tab);

focusTopLeftInputArea(anchor);
```

and focusTopLeftInputArea find a TextInputControl "ti" and call ti.requestFocus().

focusTopLeftInputArea works fine finding the TextInputControl but the control doesn't get focused.

Comment: I've had a similar problem with in app, read the rules on [requestFocus](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#requestFocus()), in my case there was a problem with an ancestor node

Answer (score 1):

From the JavaFX Api Documentation of the Node's requestFocus Method:

> To be eligible to receive the focus, the node must be part of a scene,
>   it and all of its ancestors must be visible, and it must not be
>   disabled.

So where exactly do you call this code from? Make sure that the time you call requestFocus, your control is already part of a scene/stage and the call is done in the JavaFX Application thread (this can be ensured by calling it via `Platform.runLater()`).

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian. Apparently mi control is not part of a scene. I've tried exploring the scenegraph's nodes recursively, printing node.getScene(), and it works until it reaches a ScrollPane, then for all children of the ScrollPane content node.getScene() returns null.
Any clue?

Comment: Without further knowledge about your application i can only guess what the issue is. From your description it seems that you are creating the content for a tab pane but never adding it to your scene. It would be helpful if you post your skeletal application structure into your question.